# Change the color of a 3D image pixel and save it

Tags: python, 3d, pixel

I have a 3D array. I want to change some pixel color of this 3D image.
I want to change the pixel color for a given condition that is if my mask pixel for a fixed 3D co-ordinate is not equal 0 then I want to change my 3D array pixel to red color. Finally, I want to save this into a nifty format or .nii.gz format. I write some code this way, but this code gives me an error

```
  x, y, z=volume.shape
  for i in range (0, x):
     for j in range (0, y):
        for k in range (0, z):
           if(detections[i,j,k] !=0 ):
                volume[i ,j, k]=(255, 0, 0)
   ni_img = nib.Nifti1Image(output, volume.affine)
   nib.save(ni_img, '/content/SpineFinder-master/3d_path/output.nii.gz')



ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence volume[i, j, k]=(255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: How many dimensions does the volume have? I assume it's grayscale?

Comment: Yes. It's grayscale.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to write a color 3D NIfTI with NiBabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534333/how-to-write-a-color-3d-nifti-with-nibabel)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error is because you can't 'just' write RGB values to nifti files.
Please look up the question attached:
[How to write a color 3D NIfTI with NiBabel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40534333/how-to-write-a-color-3d-nifti-with-nibabel)

Answer (score -1):

I'd start with the missing comma (between i & j) in

```
volume[i j, k]=(255, 0, 0)
```

Comment: Sorry, this is a typo mistake when I write my question.I updated it.